# Issue with arrays

Tags: java, bukkit

I have an issue with an Array while developing a Bukkit Plugin. Why doesn't this work? It is supposed to check whether the player has already placed the block. It keeps on saying "Diamonds!!" ingame.

```
@EventHandler
public void OnPlaceofDiamond(BlockPlaceEvent e){
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    String storage[] = new String[100];
    int i = 0;

    if(e.getBlock().getType() == Material.DIAMOND_BLOCK){
        if(Arrays.asList(storage).contains(player.getName())){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "You are on the list");
        }else{
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "DIAMONDS!!");
            storage[i] = player.getName();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you give will always add the player name to storage[0] because every time you call the method, `storage[i] = player.getName()` always has i as 0. Could this be ovewriting the player names you want to check for?

Comment: Why are you even using an array for this purpose, when something like a `LinkedList` would work just as well (and you wouldn't convert it into a list every single time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your creating a new `storage` array every time a player places a block:

```
@EventHandler
public void OnPlaceofDiamond(BlockPlaceEvent e){
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    String storage[] = new String[100];
```

So you'll never have the complete list of players. To fix this, you should declare the `Array` outside of your method:

```
String storage[] = new String[100];

@EventHandler
public void OnPlaceofDiamond(BlockPlaceEvent e) {
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    int i = 0;

    if(e.getBlock().getType() == Material.DIAMOND_BLOCK){
        if(Arrays.asList(storage).contains(player.getName())){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "You are on the list");
        }
        else{
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "DIAMONDS!!");
            storage[i] = player.getName();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that every time the `BlockPlaceEvent` event is called, an entirely new `storage` array is created. If you want `storage` to not be recreated on every event call, you have to place it outside of the method declaration like this:

```
String storage[] = new String[100];

@EventHandler
public void OnPlaceofDiamond(BlockPlaceEvent e) {
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    int i = 0;
    //The rest of your code below
}
```